# Copy-to-clipboard icon for code blocks

Tags: icon

## My problem

I am building a tutorial site with code blocks that the user should copy and paste into their console. I would like to add a copy button to the code snippets that would intuitively make them click on it on order to copy the code in the block.

I found quite a few icons, and I wonder whether there is a convention for such a copy-code-text icon.

## What have I tried

- Searched "Copy Icons", "Copy to console icon" and so on
- Looked at a few sites with code samples, but found nothing cnclusive

## My question

**What is the right icon for the "copy code in snippet" action in an HTML page?**

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this.

The  is pretty universally used to reference code for HTML vs {} that we use on here for other forms of code.

A generic copy icon behind it works nicely and then you could have a "toggle state" for pasting the copied code. You could even use a scisors.

Try out some combinations and see what you come up with!

[image]